# How effective a barrier is a atomic write followed by an atomic read of the same variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model, memory-fences

Consider the following:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<unsigned> var;
unsigned foo;
unsigned bar;

unsigned is_this_a_full_fence() {
     var.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
     var.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
     bar = 5;
     return foo;
}
```

My thought is the dummy load of var should prevent the subsequent variable accesses of foo and bar from being reordered before the store.

It seems the code creates a barrier against reordering - and at least on x86, release and acquire require no special fencing instructions.

Is this a valid way to code a full fence (LoadStore/StoreStore/StoreLoad/LoadLoad)? What am I missing?

I think the release creates a LoadStore and StoreStore barrier. The acquire creates a LoadStore and LoadLoad barrier. And the dependency between the two variable accesses creates a StoreLoad barrier?

EDIT: change barrier to full fence. Make snippet C++.

Comment: This is not C++

Comment: Unclear question, since without [MCVE]

Comment: Updated to make it C++.

Comment: Is there anything in the C++ standard that requires the atomicity of `std::atomic<>` to apply to anything other than the variable in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major issue with this code is that the store and subsequent load to the same memory location are clearly not synchronizing with any other thread. In the C++ memory model races are undefined behavior, and the compiler can therefore assume your code didn't have a race. The only way that your load could observe a value different from what was stored is if you had a race. The compiler can therefore, under the C++ memory model, assume that the load observes the stored value.

This exact atomic code sequence appears in my C++ standards committee paper [no sane compiler would optimize atomics](http://wg21.link/n4455) under "Redundant load eliminated". There's [a longer CppCon version of this paper on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB57wIf9W1k).

Now imagine C++ weren't such a pedant, and the load / store were guaranteed to stay there despite the inherent racy nature. Real-world ISAs offer such guarantees which C++ doesn't. You provide some happens-before relationship with other threads with acquire / release, but you don't provide a *unique total order which all threads agree on*. So yes this would act as a fence, but it wouldn't be the same as obtaining sequential consistency, or even total store order. Some architectures could have threads which observe events in a well-defined but different order. That's perfectly fine for some applications! You'll want to look into IRIW (independent reads of independent writes) to learn more about this topic. The x86-TSO paper discusses it specifically in the context of the ad-hoc x86 memory model, as implemented in various processors.

Comment: Thanks! How does the compiler know it's not synchronizing?

Comment: FWIW, I'm using it as to get a #StoreLoad barrier - so that the local CPU doesn't reorder any reads before the `var.store`. This is useful in algorithms where the store indicates an acknowledgement of receipt of a notification. We want to make sure that we see all the state changes (to other variables) that preceded the notification. If I can get past the C++ undefined behavior issues, the ISA stuff might be good enough to support that.

Comment: The load acquire would need to be in a loop that tries to observe a change in value for this to synchronize with another thread. The compiler knows that's not the case, you're clearly not synchronizing with another thread between the store and the load. That's in N4455. You could just drop a `std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` between the store and the load. That generates zero code, but tells the compiler you might have a signal change things in the middle, and acts somewhat like `asm volatile ("":::"memory");`. It's super sketchy but Should Work for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo-code (which is not valid C++) is not atomic as a whole.

For example, a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) could happen between the store and the load and some other thread would become scheduled (or is already running on some other [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)) and would then change the variable in between. Context switches and [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) can happen at every machine instruction.

> Is this a valid way to code a barrier

No, it is not. See also [pthread_barrier_init(3p)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_barrier_init.3p.html), [pthread_barrier_wait(3p)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_barrier_wait.3p.html) and related functions.

You should read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (in practice, C++11 threads are a tiny abstraction above them) and consider using mutexes.

Notice that [`std::memory_order`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) affects mostly the current thread (and what it is observing), and do not forbid it from being interrupted/context-switched ...

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175962/841108).

Comment: The OP is referring to the type of barrier that prevents memory reordering (the one that is used in lock-free code). - `pthread_barrier_wait` offers different functionality

Comment: But my answer holds: context switch can happen between `var.store` & `var.load`

Comment: Apologies, I was unclear. I'm not trying to give an example of a cross-thread synchronization primitive. I'm presenting a toy example to try to understand C++ memory model and fences better. Fences would have probably been a better word than barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you run this code in multiple threads, using ordering like this is not correct because the atomic operations do not synchronize (see link below) and hence `foo` and `bar` are not protected.

But it still may have some value to look at guarantees that apply to individual operations.
As an acquire operation, `var.load` is not reordered (inter-thread) with the operations on `foo` and `bar` (hence #LoadStore and #LoadLoad, you got that right).
However, `var.store`, is not protected against any reordering (in this context).

#StoreLoad reordering can be prevented by tagging both atomic operations `seq_cst`. In that case, all threads will observe the order as defined (still incorrect though because the non-atomics are unprotected).

EDIT
`var.store` is not protected against reordering because it acts as a one-way barrier for operations that are sequenced before it (i.e earlier in program order) and in your code there are no operations
before that store.
`var.load` acts as a one-way barrier for operations that are sequenced after it (i.e. `foo` and `bar`).

Here is a basic example of how a variable (`foo`) is protected by an atomic store/load pair:

```
// thread 1
foo = 42;
var.store(1, std::memory_order_release);

// thread 2
while (var.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 1);
assert(foo == 42);
```

Thread 2 only continues *after* it observes the value set by thread 1.. The store is then said to have synchronized with the load and the assert cannot fire.

For a complete overview, check Jeff Preshing's [blog articles](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics).

Comment: I thought the release semantics on the `var.store` would prevent memory accesses before it from being reordered past the `store`. Could you please elaborate on: However, `var.store`, is not protected against any reordering (in this context).

Comment: @ConstantineSapuntzakis Fair question.. I have added an example

Comment: Thank you! Let's say that there are stores and loads before `is_this_a_full_fence()` is called. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @ConstantineSapuntzakis It changes it a little bit in that the stores & loads before that function cannot be reordered with the `var.store(release)`.. But, it's still incorrect because `foo` and `bar` can be accessed at the same time by different threads and that is not allowed. My example shows how `foo` is first written by thread 1 and thn read from by thread 2.